# what does OracleUtilities.GetConnection() function do? and how can I replace it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm currently trying to replace some REALLY old code we have here, and been replacing the oracle.dataaccess for oracle.ManagedDataAccess references, however, there seems to be some functions that are being imported from a dll called DW.Utilities, that reference is OracleUtilities.GetConnection(), and is being called on the constructor of my connection class like this

```
        {
            get
            {
                return (OracleConnection)OracleUtilities.GetConnection();
            }
        }
```

when I remove the reference to my Oracle.DataAccess dll the GetConnection function stops working, and I can't find a new reference on the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to that function, and I can't find any Oracle documentation reference for that function to know what it does, so I can replace it with something else.

Does anyone know what this function does and how can I replace it?

This is the error I'm getting

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'OracleConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.102.2.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'

Comment: OracleUtilities is your own company's class? Is that right? If so, then why would you expect us to know what it's doing, other than what we can glean from the method signature? We can't decompile it - you're the one that's presumably got the DLL somewhere so that'd be up to you.

Comment: No, OracleUtilities comes from somewhere within the older versions of Oracle.DataAccess, but I can't find documentation about it

Comment: You could decompile it. But it probably just creates an OracleConnection initialized with a connection string from a config file. Figure out what you need it to do and replace it with whatever code accomplishes that.

Comment: It is unlikely that OracleUtilities is a part of Oracle.DataAccess.dll. I happen to have used that dll in an old project, rescued it, and didn't find that class. What is the error that you are seeing, increment your question with an image or the error text.

Comment: I added the error to the initial question

Comment: yup, I just found out that this is some obscure super old code that we managed that referenced the oracle dll, when I removed the dataaccess dll the other one stopped working. I'm sorry about the confusion but I wasn't too sure myself, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we all thought.

The error says it clearly: "The type 'OracleConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced(...)".

The problem **is not** the "OracleUtilities.GetConnection();" that is probably an internal class for your company (right click on it and 'Go To Definition'), and probably returns an DbConnection.

The problem **is** the casting to OracleConnection, but this class should also exist on Oracle.ManagedDataAccess as well, did you add a reference to the dll (or the nuget package, or however you are referencing it?)

The problem can be on the OracleUtilities as well, you should really discover what that is (at least in which reference/dll it is defined?)

Answer (score 0):

yup, I just found out that this is some obscure super old code that we managed that referenced the oracle dll, when I removed the dataaccess dll the other one stopped working. I'm sorry about the confusion but I wasn't too sure myself, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the accepted answer stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers